# Create Angular $injector with custom scope?

Tags: angularjs

How can I create an Angular $injector with a custom scope? For example, so that I can inject custom values along with normal services:

```
$injector.invokeWithContext({ foo: 42 }, function($http, foo) {
  console.log(foo); // --> 42
});
```

Comment: It's being generated by my code… not sure why that's relevant?

Answer (score 0):

The `locals` argument to [`$injector.invoke`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector#invoke) can be used to override services:

```
$injector.invoke(function($http, foo) {
  console.log(foo); // --> 42
}, this, { foo: 42 });
```